# Create mutable Dictionary with dynamic value/keys in SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I need to create a Dictionary with dynamic keys.

At the end I need a Dictionary

I tried to use:

```
var animDictionary:[String:AnyObject]

    for position in 1...10
    {
        let strImageName : String = "anim-\(position)"
        let image  = UIImage(named:strImageName)
        animDictionary.setValue(image, forKey: strImageName) //NOT WORK 
       //BECAUSE IT'S NOT A NSMUTABLEDICTIONARY
    }
```

So I tried:

```
var animMutableDictionary=NSMutableDictionary<String,AnyObject>()

    for position in 1...10
    {
        let strImageName : String = "anim-\(position)"
        let image  = UIImage(named:strImageName)
        animMutableDictionary.setValue(image, forKey: strImageName) 
    }
```

But I don't find the how to convert my NSMutableDictionary to a Dictionary. I'm not sure it's possible.

In the Apple doc, I found :

[image: Apple Doc]

I don't know if it's possible to use it in my case.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Xcode 11 • Swift 5.1**

You need to initialize your dictionary before adding values to it:

```
var animDictionary: [String: Any] = [:]

(1...10).forEach { animDictionary["anim-\($0)"] = UIImage(named: "anim-\($0)")! }
```

Another option is to use `reduce(into:)` which would result in `[String: UIImage]`:

```
let animDictionary = (1...10).reduce(into: [:]) {
    $0["anim-\($1)"] = UIImage(named: "anim-\($1)")!
}
```

Comment: This looks like a perfect candidate for [`Dictionary.init(uniqueKeysWithValues:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/init(uniquekeyswithvalues:))

Comment: @Alexander I like the `reduce(into:)` approach/syntax